# How would I write this code with Reactive Programming?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I just started messing around with reactive programming, and I know just enough to write code but not enough to figure out what's happening when I don't get what I expect. I don't really have a mentor available other than blog posts. I haven't found a very good solution to a situation I'm having, and I'm curious about the right approach.

The problem:

I need to get a Foo, which is partially composed of an array of Bar objects. I fetch the Bar objects from web services. So I represented each web service call as an IObservable from which I expect 0 or 1 elements before completion. I want to make an IObservable that will:

- Subscribe to each of the IObservable instances.
- Wait for up to a 2 second Timeout.
- When either both sequences complete or the timeout happens:

  - Create an array with any of the Bar objects that were generated (there may be 0.)
  - Produce the Foo object using that Bar[].

I sort of accomplished this with this bit of code:

```
public Foo CreateFoo() {

        var producer1 = webService.BarGenerator()
                                  .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Observable.Empty<Bar>());
        var producer2 = // similar to above

        var pipe = producer1.Concat(producer2);

        Bar[] result = pipe.ToEnumerable().ToArray();

        ...
}
```

That doesn't seem right, for a lot of reasons. The most obvious is Concat() will start the sequences serially rather than in parallel, so that's a 4-second timeout. I don't really care that it blocks, it's actually convenient for the architecture I'm working with that it does. I'm fine with this method becoming a generator of IObservable, but there's a few extra caveats here that seem to make that challenging when I try:

1. I need the final array to put producer1 and producer2's result in that order, if they both produce a result.
2. I'd like to use a TestScheduler to verify the timeout but haven't succeeded at that yet, I apparently don't understand schedulers at all.
3. This is, ultimately, a pull model, whatever gets the Foo needs it at a distinct point and there's no value to receiving it 'on the fly'. Maybe this tilts the answer to "Don't use Rx". To be honest, I got stuck enough I switched to a Task-based API. But I want to see how one might approach this with Rx, because I want to learn.

Comment: It strikes me that Zip would be a better fit for your problem than Concat.

Comment: @EricLippert: Hmmm... I'd have to do a little work to make sure I got them in the right order afterwards, but I do see how that could be better.

Comment: Why is it hard to get them in order?  `firstBars.Zip(secondBars, (first, second) => new { first, second }` and now you have an observable of `{first, second}` pairs.

Comment: Now maybe this solution isn't right because if the first one times out, you still want a bar from the second one?

Comment: @EricLippert: Right, I guess Zip would block in that case. What if I had some kind of "empty result" null object, maybe? My thoughts so far all revolve around some kind of WaitHandle-based solution.

Comment: Yeah, I dont think `Zip` is what you want if the either of the two sequences can return zero results. If instead the sequence always returned one thing (and that thing was an array with 0 or many items), then `Zip` would be fine. Can you clarify the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var pipe = producer1
        .Merge(producer2)
        .Buffer(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), testScheduler))
        .Take(1);

    var subscription = pipe
        .Select(list => new Foo(list.ToArray())
        .Subscribe(foo => {} /* Do whatever you want with your foo here.*/);
```

[`Buffer`](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Buffer) takes all elements emitted during a window (in our case in two seconds), and outputs a list.

If you want to stick with your pull model, instead of a subscription you could do:

```
var list = await pipe;
var foo = new Foo(list.ToArray());

//....
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, and is behaving with the test scheduler. To accomplish the ordering, I made a class that lets me tack an integer "sort order" to any given value. Then, in the final phases, I sort that enumerable and transform it back to a sequence of strings.